# Import asp.net / SQL Server 2012 website database to local SQL Server 2014 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have website developed in asp.net and used SQL Server 2012 for database, my task to make website responsive, I have decided make changes locally first, I have whole source through ftp, and downloaded database backup from control panel.

My problem is that when I try to restore downloaded db backup file, it keeps showing me error message "No backupset selected to be restored", please check attached screen. I am new to ASP.NET / SQL Server 2012, can any one help me to solve this issue ?

[image: downloaded]

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by any number of issues.

To help get to the bottom of this I would, In SSMS open a new query window and run the following command

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DatabaseNameHere] 
FROM DISK='Path to the backup file here'
```

e.g. if my database was called AdventureWorks and the backup was located in c:\Temp\Adventureworks.bak the TSQL would be.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] 
FROM DISK='c:\Temp\Adventureworks.bak'
```

The error produced will give you a much better indication as to what the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34005/discussion-between-lawrage-and-user3782114).